# php mail form error

Tags: php

I am trying to send an email through php using this:

```
<?php
mail("my_email", "Test Message", "welcome to the test message") or die("Error!");
?>
```

But when i run this in php the email doesnt come through and no error message is created and the die message does not appear anywhere.

I have got this information from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

What have i done wrong? I have been looking but i am unable to find out if its a problem with php or my server and everything i have followed has failed.

can someone clarify this?

----EDIT----

By the looks of it i need to do some more research in this matter, thanks for all your help and ill do some more work

Comment: that is the code the only thing i havent included is the php tags <?php ?>

Comment: Is that the entire script code you're trying to run? If so it's not going to work.

Comment: Is "my_email" your email address?

Comment: mail function returns `boolean` value, `true` - message sent to delivery, `false` - error, check: `var_dump(mail(...));`

Comment: yes i took my email out so it wasnt on here but it is correct.

Comment: You do have the properly configured and working MTA on your system, right?

Comment: Well I for one, can't help you if that's your full code. SO members help, we don't "build".

Comment: @mkjasinski it returns true

Comment: if you don't have active MTA, use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Comment: @JacktheRandom i do not know what that is but i was unaware i need extra programs

Comment: @Fred I dont expect you to build it for me, im just looking for help on why it isnt working as im stumped

Comment: @NoLiver92 if returns `true`, that your MTA doesn't work correctly. You must configure that in your operating system.

Comment: @NoLiver92 http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/custom-php-contact-forms/ and http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/8.html are good starting points.

Comment: @NoLiver92 well, since you don't know what it even is, you probably don't have a properly configured MTA. So yeah, basically you need to use some other PHP class that supports sending via SMTP.

Comment: @NoLiver92 First you need a `form`, then a `mail() process` that will "process" the information sent `from the form`.

Comment: @Fred i have a form but i was trying to eliminate the possibility of errors by starting whith the basics. I obviously did not realise that i needed extra code/software

Comment: @NoLiver92 Which method did you want to use for processing, `SMTP`, `PHP mail()`, `CGI/PERL sendmail` other? And, are you running from your own server or hosted service?

Comment: @Fred i want to use php mail() if i can as i dont know how it will be hosted after i develop the website. for the time being i am hosting it on my own server

Comment: @NoLiver92 So, how did you get the results from your initial testing? Where was the file executed from? `Evan's` suggestion/answer below is definitely a `basic` way of doing it, however it's prone to `injection`. Without a proper way of testing a form, you stand at doing a lot of work for nothing.

Comment: @Fred I have a basic form which gives me variables with data which is collected using trim() and htmlentities() on the entered data to stop that. i am trying to get the mail working then ill worry about adding my form in (which i should be able to do). the code(in original post) was executed from my index page and i got my results by using mkjasinski's post above.

Comment: @NoLiver92 So, that's not your entire code then. Had you posted your entire code, I could've potentially helped. Without full source code, I can't help to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: @Fred the rest of the code is irrelevant if the mail is not working when the details are put in manually. so putting in a string or a form makes no difference they would both be the same thing. thats why the form isnt here as its not needed as a string will take the place of the variable.

so before i put the form on to it, it needs to work

Answer (score 1):

Basic implementation, however, if the above doesn't work then I'm sure you need to set up a [MTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent)

**HTML Code**

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit mail" />
</form>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
  $userEmail = $_POST['email'];
  $to = strip_tags($userEmail);
  $subject = "email subject";
  $message= 'email body message goes here';
  $headers = "From: anotheremail@test.com";

  if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
    echo "mail sent";
  }  else {
    echo "error sending mail";
  }
}
```

Comment: This is good, i have code similar. I now believe that its a MTA issue as the basic mail send did not work